# Why are my redis tests not as fast as looking up a hash from an object?

Tags: ruby, redis

I would think the the redis test would be at least equally as fast as doing a hash lookup in an object.

An object looking up a value from a hash

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :022 > quick(1000) {@p.lookup(:summary_header)}   #=> nil
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.000000   0.010000   0.010000 (  0.006522)
--------------------------- total: 0.010000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.006701)
```

vs a simple Redis lookup

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :023 > quick(1000) {r.get("header")}   #=> nil
Rehearsal ------------------------------------
   0.020000   0.020000   0.040000 (  0.088880)
--------------------------- total: 0.040000sec

       user     system      total        real
   0.030000   0.020000   0.050000 (  0.085839)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis is fast, but it can't be as fast as a direct memory access. It requires constructing a request, posting it, waiting for a response, decoding that response, and returning that value to your application. Redis runs as a separate process, so you will have to pay this price for inter-process communication even when it is located on the same machine.

That it is only twelve times slower by your benchmark is still impressive.

Comment: Why couldn't it just instantiate a local object and pull the data from it for small data sets?

Comment: If you're using Redis, you're using data stored in an external process. You can cache this, if that's what you're asking, but it's the same as MySQL or any other server process. You will have to make a request and await a response, something that will always take more time than fetching something directly from the memory allocated directly to your Ruby process.

Comment: I guess it just seems like it could auto-cache if it's not a distributed data store.

Comment: Since there's no assurance that your process will be the only one altering the Redis store, you cannot have the default behavior to be to cache it.